# Pipelets not loaded after update from Intershop 7.7 to 7.9

Tags: intershop

I updated my project from from Intershop Commerce Management 7.7 to 7.9. After that the pipelets of my app_sf_responsive* cartridges are not loaded anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipelets.resource file was missing. This could be easily fixed by applying the plugin 'com.intershop.gradle.cartridge-resourcelist' in the build.gradle file of the cartridge.

```
apply plugin: 'com.intershop.gradle.cartridge-resourcelist'
```